# Prove by Induction on n that $\exists x,y,z \in Z$ s.t. $x\ge 2, y\ge 2, z\ge 2$ satisfies $x^2+y^2=z^{2n+1}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, induction

Prove by Induction on n that $\exists x,y,z \in Z$ s.t. $x\ge 2, y\ge 2, z\ge 2$ satisfies $x^2+y^2=z^{2n+1}$

I'm a lot more comfortable with proving induction with $\forall$ I haven't really seen one of this format yet where there's an $\exists$. Since this is obviously not true for all $x,y,z\in Z$ it's harder for me to figure out how to solve it.

Comment: Do you really need to prove by induction, or did you simply assume from existence of $n$ in the equation that it should be solved by induction?  It is clear that $(x,y,z)=(2^n,2^n,2)$ works.  In fact, let $a$ and $b$ be any integers.  Set $(x,y,z)=\Big(a(a^2+b^2)^n,b(a^2+b^2)^n,a^2+b^2\Big)$.

Comment: Yea unfortunately have to use induction

Comment: If induction can be done it usually means so form of the previous statement (that there are $x,y,z: x^2 + y^2=z^{2n+1}$) ca be manipulated to another.  The "for any" is harder as you have no guidlines.  But using the $x^2+y^2 = z^{2n+1}$ the we to manipulate the RHS to a $z'^{2n+3}$ term is so multiply by $z^2$ and to manipulate the LHS to a $x'^2+y'^2$... well, that can also be done but multiplying but s$z^2$.  $(xz)^2 + (yz)^2=z^2(x^2+y^2)=z^2*z^{2n+1}=z^{2n+3}$.... and that's that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if $x^2 + y^2 = z^{2n+1}$ then

$x^2z^2 + y^2z^2 = z^{2n+1}z^2$

Answer (score 1):

**Remark.**  This problem is much easier to prove without induction.  But, well, since it is required, I will oblige.  However, if you look carefully, this is exactly the same as what I wrote in my comment under the OP's question.

For each integer $n\geq 0$, we want to find $(x_n,y_n,z_n)\in\mathbb{Z}^3$ such that $$x_n^2+y_n^2=z_n^{2n+1}\,.$$  For the basis of our induction, start with $(x_0,y_0,z_0):=(a,b,a^2+b^2)$ for an arbitrary pair $(a,b)\in\mathbb{Z}^2$.  For an integer $n\geq 1$, suppose you have $\left(x_{n-1},y_{n-1},z_{n-1}\right)$.  Define
$$(x_n,y_n,z_n):=\left(x_{n-1}z_{n-1},y_{n-1}z_{n-1},z_{n-1}\right)\,.$$
Prove that this triple $(x_n,y_n,z_n)$ satisfies $x_n^2+y_n^2=z_n^{2n+1}$.

In fact, the same argument shows that, for each $k\in\mathbb{Z}_{>0}$, there are infinitely many integers $(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{Z}^3$ or $(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{Z}_{>0}^3$ such that $$x^2+y^2=z^k\,.$$
The case where $k$ is odd has been dealt with.  For an even $k$, we start with a Pythagorean triple $(a,b,c)\in\mathbb{Z}^3$ (or $(a,b,c)\in\mathbb{Z}_{>0}^3$), i.e., $a^2+b^2=c^2$.  Then, $$(x,y,z)=\left(ac^{\frac{k}{2}-1},bc^{\frac{k}{2}-1},c\right)$$
is a solution to $x^2+y^2=z^k$.  You can, of course, write this proof inductively as well.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* The [Brahmagupta–Fibonacci identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmagupta%E2%80%93Fibonacci_identity) implies that  if $z_1$ and $z_2$ are sums of squares, then so is their product $z_1 z_2$.